# How to open form inside method, submit button and then come back to original method and continue?

Tags: c#, winforms, digital-persona-sdk

Our application requires that a witness must authenticate before a logged in user can perform enrollment operations (Enroll and Delete).
This is not an issue for Enrolling as I can add a check (IsWitnessApproved) to an `enrollment_OnStartEnroll` method I.E. before the Capture method is called and fired.

However, this is not possible for Deletion as I don't have access to a point where the `enrollment_OnDelete` method hasn't fired.

I haven't been able to get a response to this issue from *Digital Persona* so I'm now looking at work-arounds.

I'm exploring if its possible to open up a new form (`WitnessApproval`) inside the `enrollment_OnDelete` method, approve the witness in the form (`btnConfirmWitness_Click`) and then come back into the method and continue on with the deletion?

**enrollment_OnDelete method:**

```
    private void enrollment_OnDelete(DPCtlUruNet.EnrollmentControl enrollmentControl, Constants.ResultCode result, int fingerPosition)
    {
        if (!witnessApproved)
        {
            WitnessApproval witnessApproval = new WitnessApproval();
            witnessApproval.Show();
        }

        else
        {
            int fingerMask = GetFingerMask(fingerPosition);

            if (enrollmentControl.Reader != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Delete from database
                    new EnrollmentDAL().DeleteEnrolledFingerprint(Settings.Default.Username, fingerMask, txt_WitnessName.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("Fingerprint deleted.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    pbFingerprint.Image = null;
                    pbFingerprint.Visible = false;
                    btnCancel.Visible = false;
                    witnessApproved = false;
                    txt_WitnessName.Text = String.Empty;
                    txt_WitnessPassword.Text = String.Empty;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("There was a problem deleting the fingerprint.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    new Util().LogError(ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Reader Connected.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }

            _sender.Fmds.Remove(fingerPosition);
        }
    }
```

**Selected WitnessApproval methods:**

```
    private void btnConfirmWitness_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbl_Validation.Visible = false;

        if (txt_WitnessName.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            SetMessage("Please enter a Witness.");
            return;
        }
        if (txt_WitnessPassword.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            SetMessage("Please enter a Password.");
            return;
        }
        if (txt_WitnessName.Text == Settings.Default.Username)
        {
            SetMessage("User and witness cannot be the same.");
            return;
        }

        bool IsValidate = Membership.ValidateUser(txt_WitnessName.Text, txt_WitnessPassword.Text);

        Settings.Default.WitnessName = txt_WitnessName.Text;
        Settings.Default.WitnessPassword = txt_WitnessPassword.Text;

        if (IsValidate)
        {
            this.Close();
            // Allow enrollment operations
        }
        else
        {
            SetMessage("Witness credentials invalid.");
        }
    }

    private void btnCancelWitness_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        // DO NOT Allow enrollment operations
        witnessCancelled = true;
    }

    private void SetMessage(string message)
    {
        lbl_Validation.Visible = true;
        lbl_Validation.Text = message;
    }
```

Comment: Don't mix UI logic and Business Logic. If you need to get a confirm (or some kind of authentication) do it in UI layer before calling the business logic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to open form inside method, submit button and then come back to original method and continue?

There is [ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) method for this purposes.

Here is usage example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void ShowMyDialogBox()
{
   Form2 testDialog = new Form2();

   // Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
   if (testDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
   {
      // Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
      this.txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text;
   }
   else
   {
      this.txtResult.Text = "Cancelled";
   }
   testDialog.Dispose();
}
```

In your case, `Form2` is `WitnessApproval`.
In WitnessApproval Form button handlers you will also need to set `DialogResult` to `true` when the witness is approved or to `false` when user cancelled operation.

Comment: Thank you! `ShowDialog` is exactly what I was looking for.